# изменение функции create в drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

есть небольшая модель:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'ФИО', max_length = 100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name ='Телефон', max_length = 16, null=True)
    date_visit = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Дата визита', blank=True, null=True)
    time_visit = models.TimeField(verbose_name = 'Время визита', blank=True, null=True)
```

есть сериализатор

```
class VisitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Visit 
        fields = ('id','fio', 'phone','date_visit','time_visit')
```

использую `viewsets drf`

```
class RegViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer = VisitSerializer
    queryset = Visit.objects.all()
```

и в принципе все работает. Но хотелось бы добавить в api при post запросе, чтобы выполнялось такая же зависимость как и если регистрироваться через форму:

```
date_use = form.cleaned_data.get("date_visit")
time_use = form.cleaned_data.get("time_visit")
if Visit.objects.filter(date_visit=date_use,time_visit=time_use).count()<1:
    Visit.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],phone=request.POST['phone'],date_visit=request.POST['date_visit'],time_visit['time_visit'])
```

как переопределить метод create в drf?

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так

```
class RegViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer = VisitSerializer
    queryset = Visit.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        if Visit.objects.filter(date_visit=request.data['date_visit'],time_visit=request.data['time_visit']).count()<1:
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response("На текущую дату это время уже занято")

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```